# Displaying a column that a user created in a form

Tags: php, html, forms, session

Im trying to display a single column from where a user created a form, i have a table and user sessions set up. I need it so that only that column is displayed for the user that created it.

This is the form

```
<form action="core/process.php" method="post" id="registration" >
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="Product_Tracker" />

<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name_of_user']; ?>" />


<p>Name of product:<input type="text" name="Name of Product" class="input" />

<p>Please select the tests that were done on the product.</p>   
<p>In Circuit Test (ICT): Yes: <input type="radio" name="ICT" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="ICT" value="no" /></p>
<p>Visual Inspection: Yes: <input type="radio" name="Visual Inspection" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="Visual Inspection" value="no" /></p>
<p>XRAY: Yes: <input type="radio" name="XRAY" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="XRAY" value="no" /></p>
<p>Automated Optical Inspection (AOI): Yes: <input type="radio" name="AOI" value="yes" /> No: <input type="radio" name="AOI" value="no" /></p>
<!--<p>Checkbox1 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox1" /> Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox2" /></p>-->



<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<p>
<a href='access-controlled.php'>Back</a>
</p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php VDEnd(); ?>
```

Ive tried this but it doesnt work,

```
$con = mysql_connect("","","");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database",$con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_user, Name_of_product FROM Product_Tracker WHERE id_user=$_SESSION['name_of_user']");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['Name_of_Product'];
  echo "<br />";
```

this did it;

```
mysql_select_db("database",$con);

$id=$_SESSION['name_of_user'];  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_user, Name_of_product FROM Product_Tracker WHERE id_user='$id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo $row['Name_of_product'] . "<br/>";
}

mysql_query($query); 


mysql_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: you are using mysql_* which is depricated.use mysqli_*

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this

```
$id=$_SESSION['name_of_user'];    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_user, Name_of_product FROM Product_Tracker WHERE id_user='$id'");
```

Comment: I changed it to `mysql_select_db("database",$con);
$id=$_SESSION['name_of_user'];    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_user, Name_of_product FROM Product_Tracker WHERE id_user='$id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['Name_of_Product'];
  echo "<br />";`  Still doesn't display anything, i think theres something wrong with the echo

Comment: echo "SELECT id_user, Name_of_product FROM Product_Tracker WHERE id_user='$id'";
direct run in mysql database and check your query is working or not